# How to turn motor counter-clockwise

Tags: arduino

Currently, my code below turns on the motor, delays for a bit then starts again. This is all being done in the clockwise direction, however how can I write my code so it can turn counter-clockwise?

```
int motorPin = 3;

void setup() 
{ 
pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
} 


void loop() 
{ 
startStopMotor(135);
delay(1000);
startStopMotor(0);
delay(1000);
}

void startStopMotor(int speed){
  analogWrite(motorPin, speed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the code you share i'am guessing you are running a low power 5v dc motor... but you should edit your answer to give us what type of hardware you are using. This is not an answer but an idea of what you should be looking for... Basically on the motor i suppose you have, you have pin 1 and pin 2. Pin 1 is connected to a PWM signal and pin 2 is connected to ground. This configuration allows you to run your motor clock'wise. To run your motor counter clock'wise you need to invert the direction of the current basically have pin 1 connected to ground and pin 2 connected to a PWM signal.

Now there are multiple ways of doing this, i am unsure of the exact code to do this on an arduino but your pin 1 and 2 will be connected each to a PWM pin. In the code you will need to tell the arduino to put Pin 1 or 2 as a pullDown pin which basically mimics a ground thus telling the direction the other pin will output a PWM

this is not example code but it will give you an idea of what it should look like

`void loop(){
    //move clock'wise
    pin1.pullup();
    pin2.pulldown();
    analogWrite(pin1, 180);
    //move counterclock'wise
    pin2.pullup();
    pin1.pulldown();
    analogWrite(pin2, 180);
}`